# Following code don't work on other Browsers

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have code for some Test/Quiz and it can't run corectly on google chrome,Internet Explorer and other browsers except Mozilla Firefox.
Can anyone help me?
This is the following code will show you specific questions if you click,you'll see it.

```
<div id="showDiv"  style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Volvo?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Volvo? 
</form></div>
<div id="placeDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Saab?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Opel? 
</form></div>
<div id="makeDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Opel?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Opel? 
</form></div>
<div id="createDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Audi?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Audi? 
</form></div>
<select id="car" value="Show Div" >
<option value="volvo" name="volvo" onclick="showDiv()">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab" name="saab" onclick="placeDiv()">Saab</option>
<option value="opel" name="opel" onclick="makeDiv()">Opel</option>
<option value="audi" name="audi" onclick="createDiv()">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And following javascript code:

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('makeDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('createDiv').style.display = "none";   
}
function placeDiv() {
document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('makeDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('createDiv').style.display = "none";   
}
function makeDiv() {
document.getElementById('makeDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "none"
document.getElementById('createDiv').style.display = "none";
}
function createDiv() {
document.getElementById('createDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('makeDiv').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

So as you can see that is all of code.
First run it in Mozilla then in Internet explorer or Google chrome,Please if anyone can help :(.
Thank you!

Comment: @LOL: It doesn't matter how you capitalize the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Yes It's something problem with Div i think or javascript..

Comment: for future advice please try to post the code where the problem is. Long code some time will leave unanswered.
Make it relevant to others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: “Don't work” is not a problem description. Tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The `click` event on `option` elements is not reliably supported cross-browser.

Use the `change` event on the `select` element instead. (This will also eliminate a **lot** of repetitive code.) Note that as RobG points out below, on some browsers if the user moves through the list of options with the cursor keys, `change` will get fired immediately; other browsers won't fire it until the select box loses focus.

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/niseluye/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showDiv"  style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Volvo?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Volvo? 
</form></div>
<div id="placeDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Saab?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Opel? 
</form></div>
<div id="makeDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Opel?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Opel? 
</form></div>
<div id="createDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > 
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="drive">Do you drive Audi?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="love">Do you love Audi? 
</form></div>
<select id="car">
<option value="volvo" name="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab" name="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel" name="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi" name="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script>
  (function() {
    // Get the select box
    var select = document.getElementById("car");

    // Hook the change event
    select.onchange = handleSelectedCar;

    // Set up for the default value of the select
    handleSelectedCar();

    // Function to handle the setup for a car
    function handleSelectedCar() {
      var name = select.value;

      // Replace the following with the code to show/hide your divs
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "Currently-selected car: " + name;
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i  use "change" and replace it with "select" i will now have a drop down menu...

Comment: @user3537210: *"If i use "change" and replace it with "select"..."* Huh? *"...i will now have a drop down menu"* Do you mean a drop-down select? You already have one.

Comment: Note that in IE if a user navigates the options using the cursor keys, a change event will be dispatched each time a new option is selected whereas other browsers wont fire a change until the select loses focus.

Comment: Yes but where can i use this "change"  that you answered me I don't understand you

Comment: @user3537210: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Select` with `JavaScript` as below.
It will works in all browsers.

```
 <select name="type" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="alert('Changed.');">
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='2'>Two</option>
      <option value='3'>Three</option>
      <option value='4'>Four</option>
    </select>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHandler(target){
    alert(target.value);
}
</script>
<select id="abc" onchange="changeHandler(this);">         
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='2'>Two</option>
      <option value='3'>Three</option>
      <option value='4'>Four</option>

</select>
```

Or
**Updated**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHandler(target){
    if(target.value == "Mustang" ){
        document.getElementById('div_id_Mustang').style.display = "block";
    }
    if(target.value == "Viper" ){
        document.getElementById('div_id_Viper').style.display = "block";
    }
    if(target.value == "Corvette" ){
        document.getElementById('div_id_Corvette').style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
<select id="cars" onchange="changeHandler(this);">
  <option value="Mustang">Mustang</option>
  <option value="Viper">Viper</option>
  <option value="Corvette">Corvette</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope,if i chane it it will be so much different than what i want to do.
I don't want to change this code.I want to keep this code but just to add something which will help to run in other browsers.

Comment: @user3537210: That makes no sense. "I don't want to change this code" and "I want it to work in other browsers" are incompatible statements. To make it work in other browsers, you *have* to change the code.

Comment: Yes but i don't want to show me black screen and tell me i chosed 2 .I want to be like on my first code...

Comment: @user3537210 yes thats make no sense. you have to change code according your requirement. we can only provide you help, can't write for you. this is against SO rules. so please don't try to spoon feeding.

Comment: ok no problem. you have to search more or wait till another answer. your post code is too long. please make it relevant to others.